# Working with Python strings, lists, and data (copy paste multilines)

Tags: python, string, list, split

I am having some problems with the text format I am trying to process with Python.

I have a list of data in this format:

00x0x00 1

10x1x11 2

13x2x27 6

I am trying copy paste that list into terminal/[Pygame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame) window so that I can process it.

This I have figured out, but I can’t figure out: How do I separate 00x0x00 and 1?

I have tried using *str.split*, but when I do so I get some "random" text, instead of the split list I'm trying to get...

```
            textstring = pygame.scrap.get("text/plain;charset=utf-8").decode()
            print(textstring)

            thislist = textstring.replace(' ', ',')
            thatlist = thislist.split(',')
            print(thislist)
            print(thatlist)
```

Replacing space with comma works just fine, but I can’t split the string/list with comma either.

I also tried splitting with '/n' too, with the same effect as described.

This is the output when I run the following with the list written above.

```
00x0x00,1

10x1x11,2

13x2x27,6
['0\x000\x00x\x000\x00x\x000\x000\x00',
'\x001\x00\r\x00\n\x00\r\x00\n\x001\x000\x00x\x001\x00x\x001\x001\x00',
'\x002\x00\r\x00\n\x00\r\x00\n\x001\x003\x00x\x002\x00x\x002\x007\x00', '\x006\x00\x00\x00']
```

Entire code:

```
import pygame

SCREEN_WIDTH = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
pygame.scrap.init()
pygame.scrap.set_mode(pygame.SCRAP_CLIPBOARD)

thislist = ""
textstring = ""
thatlist = ""

screen.fill(WHITE)
running = True
while running:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False

        elif event.key == pygame.K_v and event.mod & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:
            textstring = pygame.scrap.get("text/plain;charset=utf-8").decode()
            print(textstring)

            thislist = textstring.replace(' ', ',')
            thatlist = thislist.split(',')
            print(thislist)
            print(thatlist)

    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **str** instead of **decode**:

```
text = b'''00x0x00 1

10x1x11 2

13x2x27 6'''
textstring = str(text, 'utf-8')
print(textstring)

thatlist = textstring.split()
print(thatlist)
```

And this is the result you want:

```
00x0x00 1

10x1x11 2

13x2x27 6
['00x0x00', '1', '10x1x11', '2', '13x2x27', '6']
```